# React Virtualized Table change selected row color

Tags: react-virtualized

I am new to react virtualized concepts and am using a RV Table decorated with Autosizer to display contents from my list. Currently, when I select a row, I dispatch an action to react-redux to update the state in store based on selected row data. This seems to work. I would also like to add a visual cue of "row selected" like a background color or text color and I have not been able to achieve that.

I tried using the rowRenderer function to set style but it does not seem to be working. Can someone share a simple example of how I can change the selected row on a RV table? When I select it once, I want the color changed and reselecting the same row should undo the color background.

Comment: can you share an example of the code you have that's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working example to highlight row on selection. To deselect highlighted row, you can tweak logic in rowStyleFormat function

```
import React from 'react'
import { Column, Table } from "react-virtualized";
import "react-virtualized/styles.css";

class TestTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: -1,
      data: [
        { 'rank': 1, 'player': 'Michael Jordan', 'points': 30 },
        { 'rank': 2, 'player': 'Wilt Chamberlain', 'points': 30 },
        { 'rank': 3, 'player': 'Bill Russell', 'points': 15 },
      ]
    }
  }

  handleRowSelect(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        index: event.index
      }
    )
  }

  rowStyleFormat(row) {
    if (row.index < 0) return;
    if (this.state.index === row.index) {
      return {
        backgroundColor: '#b7b9bd',
        color: '#333'
      };
    }
    return {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      color: '#333'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table width={500} height={300} headerHeight={20} rowHeight={30}
        rowCount={this.state.data.length} rowGetter={({ index }) => this.state.data[index]}
        onRowClick={this.handleRowSelect.bind(this)} 
        rowStyle={this.rowStyleFormat.bind(this)}
        >
        <Column width={100} label='Rank' dataKey='rank' />
        <Column width={150} label='Player' dataKey='player' />
        <Column width={150} label='Points' dataKey='points' />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default TestTable;
```